# Passing DataTable to Table-Valued Parameter in stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So, I need to pass a table-valued parameter (filled from selected options in CheckBoxLists) to a stored procedure in order to retrieve recipes that match some of the criteria inside my table-valued parameter, but when I try to do it, it doesn't return anything. I am working on ASP.Net and C#.

SQL Server Stored Procedure

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Filtros AS TABLE
(
    Categoria NVARCHAR(50),
    Dificuldade NVARCHAR(50),
    Duracao NVARCHAR(50)
);
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPesquisarReceita] (@TVP dbo.Filtros READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT R.NomeReceita, C.NomeCategoria, DF.Dificuldade, D.Duracao, R.ClassificacaoGeral, R.DataPublicacao, R.Foto, R.NumVisualizacoes, R.IDReceita
        FROM dbo.Receitas R 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Categorias C ON R.IDCategoria = C.IDCategoria
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Dificuldade DF ON R.IDDificuldade = DF.IDDificuldade
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Duracao D ON R.IDDuracao = D.IDDuracao
        WHERE R.IDEstado = 1 AND C.NomeCategoria IN (SELECT Categoria FROM @TVP) OR DF.Dificuldade IN (SELECT Dificuldade FROM @TVP) OR D.Duracao IN (SELECT Duracao FROM @TVP)
END
```

The code I used to fill the DataTable used as my TVP is correct, cause I tested it by printing its contents to a label. So the DataTable is receiving and storing properly the options being selected in the checkboxlists.

C# for the Stored Procedure and the DataTable to store the resulting data from the Stored Procedure

```
public SqlDataReader receitaPesquisada(DataConnection conn, string pesquisa, DataTable tabelaParam)
{
    SqlDataReader drObterReceita = null;

    try
    {
        string strCmmd = "uspPesquisarReceita";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strCmmd, conn.Connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Pesquisa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pesquisa;
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@TVP", tabelaParam);
        param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        param.TypeName = "dbo.Filtros";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);


        drObterReceita = command.ExecuteReader();

        return drObterReceita;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Algo correu mal no método" + ex.ToString());

        return drObterReceita;
    }
}

public DataTable imprimirReceitaPesquisada(string pesquisa, DataTable tabelaParam)
{
    DataConnection conn = new DataConnection();

    DataTable dtbReceitaPesquisada = new DataTable();

    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("NomeReceita", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Categoria", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Dificuldade", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Duracao", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("ClassificacaoGeral", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("DataPublicacao", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("Foto", typeof(string));
    dtbReceitaPesquisada.Columns.Add("NumVisualizacoes", typeof(string));

    try
    {
        conn.openConnection();

        SqlDataReader drObterReceita = this.receitaPesquisada(conn, pesquisa, tabelaParam);

        while (drObterReceita.Read())
        {
            dtbReceitaPesquisada.Rows.Add(drObterReceita[0].ToString(), drObterReceita[1].ToString(), drObterReceita[2].ToString(), drObterReceita[3].ToString(), Math.Round(double.Parse(drObterReceita[4].ToString()), 1).ToString(), drObterReceita[5].ToString(), drObterReceita[6].ToString(), drObterReceita[7].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Algo correu mal no método" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.closeConnection();
    }
    return dtbReceitaPesquisada;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code creates and adds a nvarchar parameter to the command. Your TVP parameter never gets added or used.

Comment: Thank you SMor for the input! Well spotted. However, even after adding the parameter it is still not working. The page just doesn't display anything.

Comment: `Filtros` != `Filters`

Comment: `param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;` Also you should really dispose connection, command and reader objects with `using`

Comment: You are right @AlexanderPetrov. That was wrong, but was indeed a typo when writing the  post. The Type Table and TypeName have the same name. Thank you though!

Comment: Hi @Charlieface. I tried what you suggested but still not working. Could you briefly explain the advantages of utilizing using? Thank you!

Comment: A Table parameter is always readonly, so you should specify that it is `Input`. And disposing properly means that you don't end up with dangling connections or readers in the event of an exception. The former will probably help for performance, the latter is certainly needed as part of defensive coding

Comment: Yeah, I have added the Input. Interesting, make sense. I am kinda new to this so I am not really aware of how using works. I am assuming it is just something that is called in the moment and then is disposed of. Do you have a link or something for reference? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by @Alexander Petrov , you are declaring a table type with name dbo.filters

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Filters AS TABLE
```

but in stored procedure definition you are passing a table variable of type dbo.filtros

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPesquisarReceita] (@TVP dbo.Filtros READONLY)
```

it should be of type dbo.filters.

Moreover, always be very careful when using both AND and OR operator in where clause without parentheses " ( ) ", as due to precedence of AND over OR in SQL, your intended condition might not give you expected results.

Let me explain, below is the where which you have used

```
WHERE R.IDEstado = 1 AND C.NomeCategoria IN (SELECT Categoria FROM @TVP) OR DF.Dificuldade IN (SELECT Dificuldade FROM @TVP) OR D.Duracao IN (SELECT Duracao FROM @TVP)
```

if you run your query, in your result set you will see results where R.IDEstado = 1 and C.NomeCategoria have a value from Categoria column in @TVP, **both of these have to be true.** After this AND is evaluated other OR condition will be evaluated.

but, you might want your result with first condition

```
R.IDEstado = 1
```

to be mandatorily true and any one or more than one conditions from

```
C.NomeCategoria IN (SELECT Categoria FROM @TVP) OR DF.Dificuldade IN (SELECT Dificuldade FROM @TVP) OR D.Duracao IN (SELECT Duracao FROM @TVP)
```

should be true, however you are not clearly getting that from your query as explained above.

So you should use the where as below, all OR conditions enclosed in Parentheses:

```
WHERE R.IDEstado = 1 AND (C.NomeCategoria IN (SELECT Categoria FROM @TVP) OR DF.Dificuldade IN (SELECT Dificuldade FROM @TVP) OR D.Duracao IN (SELECT Duracao FROM @TVP))
```

**Note: You might have used AND and OR conditions as indented in your query, I am just explaining the implications using AND and OR condition without Parentheses in where clause which may or may not affect your case.**

Comment: Hi @PankajSanwal! Thank for your long post. Indeed the Filtros vs dbo.Filters was a typo on my part when writing the post. These two have the same name. I have tried your suggestion in SQL which actually makes a lot of sense, and that is exactly what I want but I am still getting no results. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I solved my issue. The problem was that I was retrieving the values from the checklistbox and putting them in a DataTable after the user clicked a search button.

However, when the user clicked the search button it redirected him to a different page. In this page which displayed the results of the search, I was calling the method that filled my DataTable based on the selected checkboxlist options. But since I redirected him to a different page, the postback rendered my DataTable with the checkboxlist values completely useless.

Instead, I assigned the DataTable to a Session variable, and called it in the new page after the redirect. Worked like a charm! Thank you everybody.